# how to get alerts count ,how many times the alerts fired for last one week in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator

sum by(alertname) (changes(ALERTS_FOR_STATE[24h])) this is giving me all the states.
i need only like only how many alerts went to critical for last one week (already fired).
need assist please.

thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The grafana alert engine publishes some internal metrics about itself, these metrics might help you to solve your requirement.

| Description |
| --- |
| Total number of alerts |
| Alert execution result |
| Notifications sent counter |
| Alert execution timer |

You can read more on internal metrics [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/view-server/internal-metrics/) and [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/#metrics-from-the-alert-engine)

Comment: This question is about alerts in Prometheus and Alertmanager, but this answer refers to alerts in Grafana.